# Tls1.0 between client and server Windows not working

Tags: encryption, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, x509certificate

I am trouble getting TLS 1.0 working between a client, which is a Windows Xp machine and a server, which is a Server 2008 R2. On the server the event log shows the message saying that TLS 1.0 connection was received from a remote a client by none of the cipher suites from the client are supported by the server.

Now I have TLS 1.0 definitely enabled on IE and all I see is that the page cannot be displayed. The connection does work in Firefox and Chrome. I have tried a number of different IE browsers and the situation is the same.

The certificates used on both the client and the server were issued on the XP machine using Visual Studio 2010 makecert utility tool.

So, my question is how do I enable all ciphers on the server or client? Or does anyone know I can fix this problem between XP and Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

I do not recomment to enable **ALL** cipher suites on client/server. Please enable only CipherSuites which are considered as [secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit).

If you want to change the CipherSuites IE is using have a look at [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2007/11/06/changing-the-ssl-cipher-order-in-internet-explorer-7-on-windows-vista.aspx).

If you want to change the CipherSuites on your server you've chosen.